# Convert Query from Codeigniter to Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

How to write this query in laravel? this query was used in Codeigniter

```
$ci->db->query("SELECT ratings.rating_id," . $table . "." . $namefield . " as thenamefield,ROUND(AVG(ratings.rating_num),2) as rating 
            FROM ratings," . $table . " WHERE " . $table . "." . $idfield . " = ratings.rating_id GROUP BY rating_id 
            ORDER BY rating DESC LIMIT " . $limit . "");
```

Comment: Instead of making a pure code writing requests you should instead tell us what you tried so far.

Comment: Please read the Laravel docs and at least give it a try. this is well documented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$select_part =  $table . "." . $namefield; 
     DB::table('ratings')
        ->select('ratings.rating_id',DB::raw("{$select_part} as thenamefield"),DB::raw("ROUND(AVG(ratings.rating_num)2) as rating"))
        ->crossJoin($table)
        ->whereRaw("{$select_part} = ratings.rating_id")
        ->groupBy("rating_id")
        ->orderByRaw("rating DESC")
        ->limit($limit)
        ->get();
```

Comment: You can do `select("{$select_part} as thenamefield")` without `DB::raw()` and there's no  need to use `"` in the `limit()` function (`limit($limit)`). Also, there's a missing a `,` in `round()` function (`round(avg(ratings.rating_num), 2)`),